# Class instance representation to something other than a string

Tags: python-3.x, class, return, representation

I have not been able to find the answer to this question, but maybe I have been asking it incorrectly or dont know the correct keywords. So....

How can I call a custom class instance, and have it return something other than gibberish, and also something other than a string?

For instance, if I create a list `mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]` and then type 'mylist' into the command line, it returns the list I created

```
mylist
Out[16]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The same is true for other aspects of Python, like a dataframe

```
a = pd.DataFrame()
a
Out[18]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

How do I have something like this happen with a custom class? Something like, calling the class instance returns one of its defining attributes, or something similar (other than a string). Is this possible (or a typical practice?) instead of returning

```
<__main__.MyClass at stuff>
```

Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the special methods [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) and [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__):

```
class A:

    def __str__(self):
        # if __str__ isn't defined, it will default to __repr__
        return 'A description for print'

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'This description will appear in the REPL'
```

Example:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a
This description will appear in the REPL
>>> print(a)
A description for print
>>>
```

Comment: So what happens if you want __repr__ to return something other than a string? Don't you get an error if you try to return something like a dictionary or a list? (Thanks for the response by the way)

Comment: It always returns a string, even for standard objects like lists; what you get in `Out[16]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` is not a list, it's a representation of your list as text : textual representations of the items of the list, separated by commas and enclosed in square brackets.